# How to set graph's orientation horizontally with neato?

Tags: orientation, graphviz, neato

Occasionally neato produces graphs having height longer than width. Is there a way to rotate the graph so that it always have width longer than height? The problems are:

- [`rankdir`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir) attribute is only for DOT
- [`landscape`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:landscape) attribute doesn't rotate the labels. Also the longest axis of the map isn't horizontal

  [image]

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:landscape

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you check that?